# Website added to Home Screen never saves log in

Tags: php, cookies, homescreen

I have this following code on the main page of my site, the site when added to the homescreen of the iphone always redirects me back to the login.php page.  Is there a way to remember that log in info or maybe remove this script from the top of the main page? Thanks for your help.  By the way if I open the site from the browser it doesnt ask to log back in unless I clear my history.

```
<?PHP
require_once("./source/include/membersite_config.php");


if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

> Check Log in function:

```
 function CheckLogin()
    {
         if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

         $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

         if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
         {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
```

> GetLoginSessionVar:

```
 function GetLoginSessionVar()
    {
        $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
        $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
        return $retvar;
    }
```

Comment: Need more information. What is $fgmembersite? What is the code for the CheckLogin function?

Comment: i am adding the checklogin function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    function CheckLogin()
    {
         session_start();

         $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

         if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
         {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: session_start(); 

// Extend cookie life time by an amount of your liking
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);

Comment: What is the `$this->rand_key` property in your code? This value mustn't change during the session. Also make sure that $_SESSION[$sessionvar] is set when the session starts.